# Can't send byte array to a local ip address using okhttp

Tags: android-studio

I have a POS machine that has a local IP as http://172.xx.xx.xx:9002. I want to send a byte array directly as raw data (without converting to any other type or serialize) to that IP using POST request with okhttp. Usually if the request success, the POS machine would give a "beep" sound, but it seems something blocking my request. I use HttpClient in Java Spring boot and it worked perfectly, but with Okhttp in android it's not. Can anyone tell me whats wrong with the Okhttp request?

- Heres the okhttp request:

```
RequestBody requestBody2 = RequestBody.create(okhttp3.MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream"), data2); //data2 is the sent byte array

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // connect timeout
                .readTimeout(59, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://172.xx.xx.xx:9002")
                .addHeader("content-type","application/octet-stream")
                .post(requestBody2)
                .build();
        Log.d(TAG, "paymentWithMBCard: " + request.header("content-type"));
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new okhttp3.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(okhttp3.Call call, IOException e) {
                Log.d("Apiheper: ", "post failed" + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();


            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(okhttp3.Call call, okhttp3.Response response) throws IOException {
                int codecheck = response.code();
                Log.d("codecheck", codecheck + "");
                if (codecheck == 200) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        String stringRes = null;
                        try {
                            stringRes = response.body().string();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        Log.d("sendPictureFace_succ:", stringRes);
                        Log.d("sendPictureFace", "running");
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("API HELPER", "" + response.code());


                }
            }
        });
```

- And here's the HttpClient request:

```
String url = "http://172.xx.xx.xx:9002";

            HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
            HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(new URI(url)).POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofByteArray(body)).build(); //body is the sent byte array

            httpClient.send(request, new HttpResponse.BodyHandler<Object>() {
                @Override
                public HttpResponse.BodySubscriber<Object> apply(HttpResponse.ResponseInfo responseInfo) {

                    return null;
                }
            });
```

Thank you